# Passing an array of integers from JavaScript to a controller action of List<int>

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, list, postdata

I am using javascript code to postdata to a controller action coded in C#. I am getting a null value when attempting to pass an array of integers in javascript created as follows:

```
var answers = [];
answers.push(1);
answers.push(2);
answers.push(3);
```

I can see from javascript alert that the values are going into array as when I try answers.tostring I am getting the value "1,2,3" as expected, I am then trying the following postdata

```
var postData = {
                'surveyID': surveyID,
                'questionID': questionID,
                'answers': answers,
                'answerText': null,
                'comment': comment,
                'questionType': questionType
            };
```

This is targetting the following controller action but the array of integers does not seem to be carrying across to the controller action as my List is always null

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult GoForward(int surveyID, int questionID, List<int> answers, string answerText, string comment, string questionType)
{}
```

Any know how I can get the postdata array to translate to a List that is not null?

Comment: Yes my question says that, I am looking for a means of passing it this way

Comment: Why cannot use `Array` class in `C#`?

Answer (score 0):

Because MVC expects the data in QueryString pattern like this:
answers=1&answers=2&answers=3

If you use jQuery to do AJAX, default is
answers[]=1&answers[]=2&answers[]=3

You could try `traditional` option

```
$.ajax({
  //...
  traditional:true,
  //...
});
```

refer to https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/