# Proper technique to pass javascript array to controller with List<int> parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I have a controller that takes a `List<int>` and I am calling from AJAX. The controller is hit, but the parameter is always `null`.

My controller:

```
public ActionResult MinorAreas(List<int> majorareas)
{
    // ...
}
```

jQuery call:

```
function onChange(e)
{
   var cur = this.value(); // an array of numbers like [2,4,7,9]

   $.ajax({
       cache: false,
       type: "GET",
       traditional: true,
       url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("GetMinorAreas"))",
       data: { "majorareas": cur},
       success: function (data) {...},
       error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {... }
   });

 }
```

Route definition:

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute(
    "GetMinorAreas",
    "minorAreas",
    new { controller="ProSearch", action="MinorAreas", majorareas=new List<int>() },
    new[] { "ABC.ZZZ.Controllers" }
);
```

Using fiddler, I can see that the URI is built correctly:

```
# With an array of [2]
http://localhost:15536/minorAreas?majorareas=2&_=1450307693166

# With an array of [2,3,9]
http://localhost:15536/minorAreas?majorareas=2&majorareas=3&majorareas=9&_=1450308261808
```

I've already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232639/passing-an-array-of-integers-from-javascript-to-a-controller-action-of-listint) about passing arrays to a controller with a `List<int>` parameter, but the solution doesn't seem to work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you edit and provide the actual network request? Your JSON may not be formatted properly.

Comment: Ohhh duh...I should have thought of that. Yes coming right up.

Comment: Added fiddler capture

Comment: It does look like the values are being passed (as separate querystring arguments), which *should* work. Does this have to be a `GET`? You might have more luck with a `POST`.

Comment: Why are you doing `majorareas=new List<int>()` in the route definition?

Comment: 1. I'm still pretty green. 2. I thought a route had to have a parameters defined...RouteParameter.Optional didn't seem right because it isn't optional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98176/discussion-between-nate-barbettini-and-gpgvm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the network request is being generated correctly. The problem is in the route definition:

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute(
    "GetMinorAreas",
    "minorAreas",
    new { controller="ProSearch", action="MinorAreas", majorareas=new List<int>() },
    new[] { "ABC.ZZZ.Controllers" }
);
```

`majorareas=new List<int>()` is going to ensure that `majorareas` is always an empty list, even when it otherwise would be populated!

You don't have to define parameters here; the **method definition** in the controller does that. Leave it off, and it should work fine:

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute(
    "GetMinorAreas",
    "minorAreas",
    new { controller="ProSearch", action="MinorAreas" },
    new[] { "ABC.ZZZ.Controllers" }
);
```